# cmake generate script with configure_file

Tags: cmake

I would like to generate small scripts (4 lines of code) at compile time that make use of CMake variables. My first approach was to use `add_custom_command` with an `echo >>` as `COMMAND`. But as CMake doesn't like long strings it's hard to generate file content on the fly.

So, my second approach is now to use `configure_file`. But now the generation is done at the configure step. Is there a way to configure a file at compile time? Maybe put a custom target on the file or something like that? Or, if not, is there a better way to write longer lines into files from CMake?

Thanks.

EDIT: the scripts are nothing special, they just utilize the ${PROJECT_NAME} variable etc. I would like to generate them at build time because if you remove a file generated a compile time it will not be regenerated unless you force cmake configuration.

Right now I am trying to solve this with `add_custom_target` + `add_custom_command` where the command is an external sh script that writes into a file but somehow the target is never built unless it depends on ALL.

Comment: can you give an example of the files you want to generate? Why would you need them to be generated at compile instead of the configure time?

Comment: you could also invoke the cmake configure step in your shell script, see http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-May/050227.html. If you can provide a small example of your CMake file, we could try to find a solution fo the dependency problem.

Comment: As m.s. said, you can use a script and give the project name as a command line argument to the script.